# In R/Shiny how to re-inforce selection of an input (selectInput) by clicking a button

Tags: r, shiny

My question is a confusing but it is simple:

I have a selecInput with 11 options. I pre-selected the first one.

I need to update this **same selection (first one)** , something like re-selection what has been selected by shiny. To do this update I include a button that selects the first option, see the code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'selection',
              label = 'options',
              choices= names(mtcars),
              selected = names(mtcars)[1]),
  
  actionBttn(inputId = 'update',"Update"),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = 'plot_1')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$update,{
      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "selection", selected = names(mtcars)[1])
    })
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = .data[[input$selection]], y = mpg)) + geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So, I want to "select again" the first option. The user will see the same chart after he clicks the button. He will see the chart been updated.

Comment: So it updates correctly when something else is selected? The default behaviour of shiny is only to renew when necessary. The flickering of the plot update is not the most reliable form of user feedback (is that what you are looking for?) since it is dependent on the server. Is [using a notification](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/notifications.html) an option maybe?

Comment: Yes this is what I want. Once is selected `names(,tcars)[1]`on shiny I would like to reinforce it. Its weird my question....its something like "click the button and make what shiny is making"

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code already does what you are describing. Can you please elaborate on the expected outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot doesn't redraw after pushing the update button if data selection isn't modified by the update.
To force redraw, you could include `input$update` in `renderPlot` so that it triggers this function.
`cat` allows to check in console that plot update was done.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'selection',
              label = 'options',
              choices= names(mtcars),
              selected = names(mtcars)[1]),
  
  actionBttn(inputId = 'update',"Update"),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = 'plot_1')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$update,{
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "selection", selected = names(mtcars)[1])
    cat('Update pressed \n')
  })
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlot({
    input$update # force update
    cat('Plot updated \n')
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = .data[[input$selection]], y = mpg)) + geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Before modification, log in console shows:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6199
Plot updated 
Update pressed 
Update pressed 
Update pressed
```

After modification:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6199
Plot updated 
Update pressed 
Plot updated 
Update pressed 
Plot updated 
Update pressed 
Plot updated
```

Comment: @Laura, did I understand your question correctly?